# drawText Canvas method not working

Tags: android

I am very new to Java and android. my 1st app using canvas and paint. for some reason I get a force close whenever I try using the drawText method.. Please help.
I am basically trying to display text in a specific x,y coordinate. which will need updates throughout game play, my code:

```
public class MyGame extends Main {

 TextView timeDisplay;
 public String clock;
 int x_pos = 10; 
 int y_pos = 100; 
 int radius = 20;
 float x = 10;
 float y = 20;
 android.graphics.Paint p;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // setup Drawing view

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        c.drawText("test", 30, 0,x,y, p);   <-- if I comment this out, no force close...
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize p as follow

```
Paint p = new Paint(); 
p.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
```

and then use

```
c.drawText("test", 30, 0,x,y, p);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Paint object "p" is never created. It contains the null pointer, hence the exception you are getting.